# An LC-unstoppable noise in a USB-powered device

Tags: power, usb, adc, noise

**EDIT:** *I found out the cause, see my answer. I would like to thank the commenters.*

I am making a USB powered device with a 12 bit ADC, from which I want to get a 8 kHz signal with a precision of about 10 bits. Yet, there is a quite complicated noise in the obtained digital signal, of different frequencies in the audio range, which limits the precision to about 5 bits.

As it turned out, there is also a ~ 100 mV, >= 1 MHz noise on the USB power line, which I guess is the cause of the problems:

[image]

So this is yet another question about a USB noise, like [this where a DC regulator is recommended](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/25951/how-to-filter-noise-from-ground) or [this where an inductance is suggested](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/127579/usb-5v-power-filtering).

Seemed easy. After a ceramic 1 uF which was there from the start, I tried the following serial sequence:

1. NCP380LSNAJAAT1G (limit charge current to 500mA).
2. A large electrolytic capacitor, 3300 uF, too large but it was at hand.
3. L1117 to trim the voltage to 3.3 V.
4. A small ceramic capacitor 1 uF.

It reduced the noise on the power line by about 20%. The other effect of the filtering above was, that in the data from the ADC some low frequencies ~ 50 Hz disappeared, but some higher-pitched noise is left:

[image]

The precision is now ~ 6 bits, a single bit better than before.

I did not yet try an inductance, but [this guy did](http://andybrown.me.uk/2015/07/24/usb-filtering/) and it reduced the noise from 100 mV like in my case to a sparse 50 mV. I am not sure if this will help in increasing the precision from 6 to 10 bits. Also, see p. 1 in the list below.

Can it be that this signal does not really come from the power line? There is an off-the-shelf microcontroller board with MK20DX256 in the same circuit, working at ~ 100 Mhz, and the power line noise is present only if it transmits the digital signal to the host. And thus it can be some interference in the cable and/or in the device, picked by the power line but also individually by different parts of the device.

Here is the simplified circuit:

[image]

Inputs of LM358 are connected as follows now: plus to a voltage divider, minus to an analog signal with a floating ground.

As seen, the microcontroller board is connected directly to the USB power, but:

1. The board has an LC filter and a 3.3 V regulator, but despite that, its Vout is about just as noisy as that from my filter.
2. Its ADC has internal Vref. I do not know, though, if it helps with such a power line.
3. My power filter is not effective anyway.

I could use a special, external, shielded ADC together with a more complex LC than that in the [link above](http://andybrown.me.uk/2015/07/24/usb-filtering/), but I only want 10 bits of precision. Would it all be really necessary?

Is there a compact solution to the problem? Or should I just power the device from another, clean source?

Comment: Have you considered that posting a schematic might be a little helpful?

Comment: It comes from PC PSU because PC PSUs are switching power supplies, and due to the chosen topology (forward or half bridge with output inductor) and cost effectiveness, designers tend to keep the ripple and noise at around %10. So 100mV is actually quite acceptable for 5V line. Anyway, for your circuit's power input, use a capacitor at input first (a few tens of pF or 100n), then a LC filter with high L and electrolytic C (dont forget to take the cutoff freq into account) then a 100n right at the VDD of your ADC chip. I also recommend using an ADC chip with high supply noise suppression ratio.

Comment: I think any ADC and µC datasheet recommends an LC filter on AVdd.

Comment: @Andy aka, I posted the schematic.

Comment: @Rohat Kılıç, there is a link in the question showing that a simple LC filter is not that effective, and also I am not sure if the noise is originally really from the power line, see the updated question; why no capacitance reduces the noise considerably? An external shielded ADC might possibly work, but is such a complication necessary? I want only 10 bits of precision.

Comment: @Janka, the uC is on a off-the shelf board wit a built-in USB socket.

Comment: Your µC board sure has an AVdd. If it doesn't, or if it is connected directly to Vdd, that board is bogus.

Comment: @Janka the board has an inductive Vin filtering and a 3.3 Vout, but it is about just as noisy as the 3.3 V after my filter. Trying out another board is an option, of course.

Comment: That's what I meant. Inductive filtering of Vin isn't sufficient as the µC itself produces noise which should not reach AVdd. That's why it has a separate AVdd input.

Comment: What is the ADC? What is the L358 - do you mean LM358? Where does the input connect to - at the moment you have a vital input pin floating in your schematic. Are all your 0V connections to a single point or could some digital noise be flowing thru the 0 volt connections that join analogue parts? Are you aware that an LM358 will only be able to generate a voltage no higher than 1.8 volt in this configuration and it has piss-poor common mode rejection at 1 MHz or higher.

Comment: @Andy aka, ADC in MK20DX256, yes LM358, its plus is connected to a voltage divider, its minus to an analog input; the 0V connections are not perfect, 1 ... 5 cm on average as it is a prototype, but does it matter that much now if there is the ~ 100 mV noise anyway?

Comment: It matters a great deal if there are digital currents at high frequencies passing down those connections. Show the full circuit and show how an input connects and state whether the input is floating (i.e. battery powered) or show what it connects regards ground. It seems to me that an LM358 is a really poor choice.

Comment: Also, the MK20DX256 spec appears to say that they are 16 bit ADCs. Can you explain your insistence of 12 bit? It also appears that your ADC references may also be subject to noise - you need to disclose what you have done to keep them clean. Are you also aware that the LM358 will likely be able to cover only about 40% of the range of those ADCs?

Comment: @Andy aka, the input is floating. Why do you think LM358 won't suffice for 8 kHz, 10 bits? Yes the ADC is 16 bit, but effectively 12 bit, of which I only want 10 bits.

Comment: Common mode rejection (as mentioned earlier) is piss-poor at 1 MHz. This means that 1 MHz noise on the LM358 power lines gets thrust onto its output. Hanging a floating signal source on the inputs produces capacitance to real ground and this can really be troublesome if the amplifier isn't designed correctly or it's a piss-poor amp like the LM358. Not using capacitors that can handle high frequencies means you can get crap on the output. Above several tens or hundreds of kHz an electrolytic capacitor starts to behave like an inductor.

Comment: Have you tried with a common mode filter?

Comment: @winny, I looked it up after reading your comment, thanks, it is an interesting concept. However, in this case, the reason was rather trivial, see my answer.

Answer (score 4):

The ADC input range is about 2 V, I wanted 10 bits. Yet the analog signal turned out to be so weak that, as seen in the schematic, I needed to set the opamp gain to 40x.

It translates to an expected differentation of input levels of about 2000 mV / 40 / 1024 = 0.05 mV. Not realising at first, that it is such a small value, **I did not shield the analog source**.

The digital signal is quite clean when the analog source is cut off near the opamp, so the **1 MHz power line noise probably does not affect a lot the sampling at a much lower frequency of 8 kHz**. I removed the voltage stabiliser, as it made the analog part work a bit worse and otherwise had no function. I kept NCP380LSNAJAAT1G + the electrolytic condenser, though, as they do remove some low frequency noise, as described in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have issues on ;

- 1) probing (remove clip and gnd wire and use only tip&sleeve
- 2) SRF of caps is too low.
- 3) ESR of Cap is too high
- 4) OA is unbalanced so CM gain is too high,  choose Diff Amp with 0.1% R arrays for gain of 40 or so.

I have covered these topics dozens of times , so you do some homework.